# Set Thread.CurrentPrincipal to current WindowsIdentity

Tags: c#, .net, console, impersonation, windows-identity

I'm writing a console application in C# .Net where i need to do some impersonation of a Windows AD account. I'v managed to set the WindowsIdentity successfully, however there is a certain Login() function call which i read executes based on the Thread's identity.

Im having a hard time understanding what the difference is between the WindowsIdentity and the Thread.CurrentPrincipal... shouldn't they be the same? How do i make the console's Thread identity run under the same impersonation?

Comment: This thread has some explanation for your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205458/why-do-thread-currentprincipal-identity-and-windowsidentity-getcurrent-differ

Comment: Saw this thread... doesn't elaborate much.